# Mysql search if last 3 records exist with same order

Tags: mysql, sql, exists

i have a table with a column of numbers

```
35
24
7
8
11
35
9
11
6
6
23
23
34
5
14
31
26
2
16
0
6
23
23
```

i want to check if the last 3 records

```
6
23
23
```

exist in previous records but with the same order and get as result the next number.

in my example :

```
6
23
23
```

exist with same order and result must be : 34

Comment: Do you have some other column that determines the order?

Comment: yes i have another column id (total 2 columns id and number)

Comment: Did you have a chance to try my answer?

Comment: yes, but i did something wrong i thing, i am new in mysql queries... i am cum-fused with the function, my table name is vista and has 2 columns id (auto integer) and numbers (varchar(2)) what i have to change because i take this error : Error Code: 1146. Table 'test.t' doesn't exist

Comment: I've updated my answer to reflect that the table is named vista and the columns id and number, please give it a try now :)

Comment: i get : Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 't1.number' in 'field list'

Comment: So change number to numbers if that is what your column is called. I've updated my answer again.

Comment: looks like works now!!! i do not know about if the results is ok, but the query run and no error!! thanks a million for your patience:)

Comment: Works fine the results are correct!!!!! Can i ask you something more please, what i should do in this case : Error Code: 1242. Subquery returns more than 1 row, i want to  to view all the rows ?

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't understand. In any case is probably better to post a new question so more people can see it and possibly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that your numbers are ordered by an auto_incremented column named `id` then this query should work:

```
select numbers 
from vista 
where id = (
    select b.id + 3 from (
      select t1.id, t1.numbers t1val, t2.numbers t2val, t3.numbers t3val 
      from vista t1 
      join vista t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1 
      join vista t3 on t1.id = t3.id-2 
      where t1.id = (select max(id) - 2 from vista)
    ) a
    join (
      select t1.id, t1.numbers t1val, t2.numbers t2val, t3.numbers t3val 
      from vista t1 
      join vista t2 on t1.id = t2.id-1 
      join vista t3 on t1.id = t3.id-2 
      where t1.id < (select max(id) - 2 from vista)
    ) b 
  on a.t1val = b.t1val 
  and a.t2val = b.t2val 
  and a.t3val = b.t3val 
  and a.id <> b.id
) 
order by id limit 1;
```

If the `id` column doesn't contain a sequence you can generate one with an appropriate row numbering query.

[Sample SQL Fiddle](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/f5242/1)